# Opening and reading XML

Tags: xml, r

I am trying to open and read a XML file for a coursera course.

According to the course's instructions, I did:

```
library(XML)
library (RCurl)
fileURL <-"https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Frestaurants.xml"
xData <- getURL(fileURL)
doc <- xmlParse(xData)
```

However, when I tried to read the file's contents with `rootNode[[1]]`, I got back obscure content.

How can I actually decipher the file within R?

Comment: what obscure content?

Comment: There is a lot, but it starts: <name>THE LAUGHING PINT</name>    <zipcode>21224</zipcode>    <neighborhood>Highlandtown</neighborhood>    <councildistrict>1</councildistrict>    <policedistrict>SOUTHEASTERN</policedistrict>    <location_1 human_address="{&quot;address&quot;:&quot;3531 GOUGH ST&quot;,&quot;city&quot;:&quot;Baltimore&quot;,&quot;state&quot;:&quot;MD&quot;,&quot;zip&quot;:&quot;&quot;}" needs_recoding="true"/>  </row>

Comment: What's obscure about that? Looks to be xml content.

Answer (score 0):

Haim,

An XML document can essentially be thought of as a tree structure, you appear to be asking how to access the root of the structure.

## RootNode Access

```
library(XML)
url <- "http://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata/data/restaurants.xml"
xmlDoc <- xmlTreeParse(file=url,useInternal=TRUE)
rootNode <- xmlRoot(xmlDoc)
xmlName(rootNode)
str(rootNode)
rootNode[[1]][[1]]
```

the latter command `rootNode[[1]][[1]]` will return:

```
> rootNode[[1]][[1]]
<row _id="1" _uuid="93CACF6F-C8C2-4B87-95A8-8177806D5A6F" _position="1" _address="http://data.baltimorecity.gov/resource/k5ry-ef3g/1">
  <name>410</name>
  <zipcode>21206</zipcode>
  <neighborhood>Frankford</neighborhood>
  <councildistrict>2</councildistrict>
  <policedistrict>NORTHEASTERN</policedistrict>
  <location_1 human_address="{&quot;address&quot;:&quot;4509 BELAIR ROAD&quot;,&quot;city&quot;:&quot;Baltimore&quot;,&quot;state&quot;:&quot;MD&quot;,&quot;zip&quot;:&quot;&quot;}" needs_recoding="true"/>
</row> 
>
```

now we have the root node, we can search the XML structure for information pertaining to particular values, for example each branches zipcode:

```
zipcode <- xpathSApply(rootNode,"//zipcode",xmlValue)
length(zipcode[zipcode==21213])
```

here for example, we find that `33` houses have a zip code of `21213` in the XML document.

## Explanation

Above and beyond this; my recommendation is you read up on the documentation

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/XML.pdf

I hope the above helps...